# Can a local procedure be bound to a variable in letrec without using lambda?

Tags: lambda, scheme, racket, letrec

I am a beginner in scheme. I used to do programs like these in using letrec and binding using lambda.

```
(define (drop l n)
  (letrec ((iter (lambda(ls x)
  (cond ((null? ls) ls)
        ((> x 1) (cons (car ls) (iter (cdr ls) (- x 1))))
        (else (iter (cdr ls) n)))))) (iter l n)))

(define factorial
  (lambda (n)
    (letrec ((iter
              (lambda (product counter)
                (if (> counter n)
                    product
                    (iter (* counter product)
                          (+ counter 1))))))
      (iter 1 1)))
```

But i recently found that the valuation authorities in our college doesn't allow the use of the construct 'lambda'. Is there anyway that similar problems could be done without using lambda? Please suggest any other alternatives.

Comment: You can use an internal `define`, which allows you to define a function without using the word `lambda`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let's examine a few variations (all in Racket).

First your original:

```
#lang racket
(define factorial
  (lambda (n)
    (letrec ((iter
              (lambda (product counter)
                (if (> counter n)
                    product
                    (iter (* counter product)
                          (+ counter 1))))))
      (iter 1 1))))

(factorial 5)
```

The first `lambda` is easily hidden:

```
(define (factorial2 n)
    (letrec ((iter
              (lambda (product counter)
                (if (> counter n)
                    product
                    (iter (* counter product)
                          (+ counter 1))))))
      (iter 1 1)))

(factorial2 5)
```

Internal defines and `letrec` are equivalent:

```
(define (factorial3 n)
  (define (iter product counter)
    (if (> counter n)
        product
        (iter (* counter product)
              (+ counter 1))))
  (iter 1 1))

(factorial3 5)
```

If you are using one of the teaching languages (for HtDP) the internal define is called a local definition - and you will have to use the `local` construct:

```
(define (factorial4 n)
  (local [(define (iter product counter)
            (if (> counter n)
                product
                (iter (* counter product)
                      (+ counter 1))))]
    (iter 1 1)))

(factorial4 5)
```

Comment: I see lambda everywhere in these examples. Fun fact: Running the macro stepper with macro hiding disabled all these look like OPs original version.

Comment: @sylwester The OP didn't say, but I am guessing the "no lambda" means that the class is using BSL (the first teaching language without explicit lambda). I find "no lambda" a peculiar requirement for a Racket program.

Comment: @soegaard if you attach a name straightaway to it, it is more concise to have no lambda..